# For loop in Laravel validation

Tags: php, laravel

How can I make something like this:

```
for($x=0; $x<=14; $x++) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'radio_'.$x => 'required',
    ]);
}
```

But I need loop only over `radio_` not `name`. Like this, but it's wrong:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required',
    for($x=0; $x<=14; $x++) {
        'radio_'.$x => 'required',
    }
]);
```

My blade file, if it will help:

```
@for($x = 0; $x <= 14; $x++)
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="radio">
            <li>@lang('leadersCompetence.questions.'.$x)</li>
        </label><br>
        @for($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++)
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="radio_{{$x}}" @if(old('radio_'.$x) == $option[$i]) checked
                       @endif value="{{$option[$i]}}" required>
                {{$option[$i]}}
            </label>
        @endfor
    </div>
@endfor
```

Comment: why are all the radio boxes required? why not use checkbox? Also please use a validation file. Also you can create a validation class to handle any custom validation case possible

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it like this by creating validation array::

```
$validate_array = ['name' => 'required'];
 for($x=0; $x<=14; $x++) {
     $validate_array['radio_'. $x] = 'required';
 }
$this->validate($request, $validate_array );
```

Comment: If it helped you please upvote the answer for helping others.

Answer (score 3):

You can put your values into *radios* array and then use

```
'radios.*' => 'required'
```

in your controller.

Comment: This requires laravel 5.2+

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, is build up a rules array and use it in the validator. For example:

```
$rules["name"] = "required";
for($x=0; $x<=14; $x++) {
   $rules['radio_'.$x] = 'required',
}
$this->validate($request, $rules);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know laravel but you can validate two times and then combine result. Or you can create that array before passing it o validation, like this:

```
$validationArray['name']= 'required';
for($x=0; $x<=14; $x++) { 
    $validationArray['radio_'.$x] => 'required', 
} 
$this->validate($request, $validationArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you see validation parameter is a array. So you can make a custom array for radios and merge it with other fields:

```
$ar = array();
for ($x = 0; $x <= 14; $x++) {
    array_push($ar, ['radio_' . $x => 'required']);
}
$validator = array_merge($ar, ['name' => 'required']);
$this->validate($request, $validator);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a loop. you can do below which validate arrays

```
$this->validate($request, [
     'name' => 'required',
     'radio.* => 'required', // change to "radio_.*" if name is radio_
]);
```