# Validation rules with dynamic file inputs

Tags: laravel, validation

My form allows users to add fields to upload a file dynamically.

```
<input type="file" name="your_file_{{ $i }}" id="your_file_{{ $i }}">
```

So it generates input names like: `your_file_1`,  `your_file_2`, ...

Now I want to make these fields mandatory through validation rules, but I can't find a way to do that.
I tried with a wildcard but it doesn't work.

```
$rules['your_file_*'] = 'required|mimes:pdf,doc,docx,png,jpg,jpeg|max:10000';
```

Any idea?

Comment: Don't use `name="your_file_{{ $i }}"`, use `name="your_files[]"`. Then, you'd be able to do `['your_files' => 'array|required', 'your_files.*' => 'mimes:...|max:10000']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for($i = 1; $i <= count($request->all()) - 1; $i++) {
    $validate_array['var'. $i] = 'required';
}

$this->validate($request, $validate_array );
```

-1 is for token csrf in post, total loop is for only dinamic input.

[For loop in Laravel validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43045823/for-loop-in-laravel-validation)

here for references

Comment: `count($request->all()) - 1` That'll work, but you can also do `count($request()->except('_token'))`. If this route was omitted from CSRF checking, and `_token` was not included, your code would have issues.

Comment: ok thanks for the tips.

Answer (score -1):

To specify a wildcard rule use dot syntax: `.*`

```php
$rules = [
    'your_file_.*' => 'required|mimes:pdf,doc,docx,png,jpg,jpeg|max:10000'
];
```

Comment: I tried it already. It doesn't work.